# jQuery plugin that takes user method

Tags: jquery, plugins, methods

I am working on a jQuery plugin and I would like for the user to pass in a method name to be executed after a flag (in the code) is set to true. I already have the flags working as needed, I just need a way to execute the method that is passed. 
For example:

```
(function(jQuery){
  $.fn.extend({  
   pluginName: function(options) {
   var defaults = {
    parameter1: 0,
    method: function(){}
   }    
   var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

      return this.each(function() {
    var opt = options;
    var flag = false;
    if(opt.parameter1 > 0){
     flag = true;
    }
    if(flag){
    //call users method
    }
                jQuery(this).hide();


      });//END return
     }//END counter method
 });//END extend 
        })//END function
        //Return jQuery object
        (jQuery);
```

The user would call it like this:

```
$("#divName").pluginName({
    parameter1: 1,
    method: function(){alert("test");}
});
```

I haven't tested the code above, it's just an illustration so you can see what I'm trying to accomplish. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you meant to start the plugin with `(function($) {...` instead of `(function(jQuery) {...` so that you can use the `$` shorthand to refer to the jQuery object inside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between a user-supplied method like your example and any other method.  Therefore, you can call it the same way you call any other method.

For example:

```
if (flag)
   opt.method();
```

If the method takes arguments, you can pass them the same way you pass arguments to ordinary methods.

Answer (score 4):

Since functions are first class objects in JavaScript, you can just use

```
options.method();
```

in your plugin to execute the function

Answer (score 1):

This comment doesn't have to do with the point of your question, but I think it's worth noting to help you learn more about jQuery and JS in general.

Your code currently reads:

```
(function(jQuery) {
  $.fn.extend({
    /* ... */
  });
})(jQuery);
```

One of the reasons for creating an anonymous function when using jQuery in this manner is so that you can reference the `$` object without conflicts with other Javascript libraries. However, you're accepting parameter with name `jQuery` into your anonymous function, and then continue on to call `$.fn.extend` instead of `jQuery.fn.extend`.

If you're planning to reference the jQuery object as `$` in your code, I recommend correcting your parameter name to `$` in the anonymous function, i.e.:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    /* ... */
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: take a look at the comments on the question :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I intended on using the jQuery namespace to avoid conflicts with other libraries; I forgot to replace all "$" with "jQuery".